# Is it defined behavior to access a base class in a union if a layout-compatible derived class member is active?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

Take e.g. the following code:

```cpp
class B {
  void *ptr = nullptr;
 public:
  auto get() { return ptr; }
};
class D : public B {};

union U {
  B b;
  D d;
};

void *func() {
  U u{.d = D{}};
  return u.b.get(); // ???
}
```

I am wondering if the line marked with `???` has undefined behavior.

The C++20 standard says in [[class.union.general]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.union#general-2):

> In a union, a non-static data member is active if its name refers to an object whose lifetime has begun and has not ended ([basic.life]).
> At most one of the non-static data members of an object of union type can be active at any time, that is, the value of at most one of the non-static data members can be stored in a union at any time.

Since `d` is the active data member at this point, this would imply that it's not allowed to read `b`. But `b` and `d` are layout-convertible, so we know that we could still access it's data member by [[class.mem.general]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.mem#general-25):

> In a standard-layout union with an active member of struct type T1, it is permitted to read a non-static data member m of another union member of struct type T2 provided m is part of the common initial sequence of T1 and T2; the behavior is as if the corresponding member of T1 were nominated.

I don't think that this is relevant though since I want to access a member function, not a data member. (At least not directly.)

Now the `B` base class subobject of `d` is the first subobject of `d` and therefore pointer-interconvertible with `d`, which is pointer-interconvertible with `u` and therefore `b`. So we end up with two pointer-interconvertible objects of the same type.
Is there some rule which allows this access based on that?
The only rule I could find about that is [[basic.compound]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.compound#4):

> If two objects are pointer-interconvertible, then they have the same address, and it is possible to obtain a
> pointer to one from a pointer to the other via a `reinterpret_cast`.

Which only seems to allow `reinterpret_cast<B*>(&u.b)->get()` which feels silly.

So is there some rule which allows this or does it rely on undefined behavior and/or compiler extensions?

(I am mostly interested in C++20 or newer drafts)

Comment: _I am wondering if the line marked with ??? has undefined behavior_ Yes, per https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.life#7.2.

Comment: _Which only seems to allow `reinterpret_cast<B*>(&u.b)->get()` which feels silly_ `reinterpret_cast<B*>(&u.b)` itself is silly, since it is unknown which object it points to: `u.b` or the base class subobject of `u.d`.